# Error bars miss-aligned in ggplot when exported to pdf

Tags: r, pdf, plot, ggplot2

When I export the pdf of the plot, the error bars are not vertically aligned. I presume this is because of the shape that I use.

The data is:

```
cat stdev   mean_old    mean_new
1   0.0214  1.5954398   1.4514398
2   0.0171  1.3915428   1.2825428
3   0.014   1.1224943   1.0731943
4   0.0187  0.8035697   0.7713697
5   0.00945 0.3998517   0.3814517
6   0.0106  0.2333042   0.2076042
```

The code is:

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(ggplot2, extrafont, scales)
font_install("fontcm")
loadfonts()

Raw_data$cat <- factor(Raw_data$cat, levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5",  "6"))
Plot1<-ggplot(data=Raw_data)+
  geom_point(aes(x=cat,y=mean_old), stat="identity", colour = "black" , alpha=1, shape=95, size=10)+
  geom_point(aes(x=cat,y=mean_new), stat="identity", colour = "red", alpha = 1,  shape=95, size=10)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_new - stdev, ymax = mean_new + stdev, x=cat), alpha = 0.5, size=0.4, width=0.1)+
  geom_text(aes(x=cat, y=mean_old, label=sprintf("%0.2f", round(mean_old, digits = 2))), vjust=-1, color='black', size=2)+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=8, color="black", angle=45, vjust=0.5),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=8, color="black"),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=8),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=8),
        plot.title=element_text(size=8),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "black"),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill="snow1"),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.text=element_text(size=45),
        legend.key.width = unit(2, "cm"),
        legend.key.height = unit(2, "cm"),
        axis.ticks = element_line(size = 0.1))+
  scale_x_discrete()+
  ylab("Means")+
  xlab("Categories")
Plot1

pdf(file.path(OutputPath, "output.pdf"),  family="CM Roman", width=4, height=6)
Plot1
dev.off()
```

What it looks like in the plots window:

[image: Output window]

What it looks like in the pdf export:

[image: pdf export]

Answer (score 0):

Something about the font is messing with the output.  I'm not exactly sure why.  Here is the PDF output with `family="CM Roman"`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something about the font is messing with the output.  I'm not exactly sure why.  It looks like a bug with either ggplot or the pdf writer.  Here is the PDF output with `family="CM Roman"`:

[image]